# execute shell script program

Tags: shell, unix

```
echo Enter 2 values: 
read val1 val2
c = `expr $val1 + $val2`
echo $c
```

While executing the shell script, I am getting the following problem:

> addition.sh: 3: addition.sh: c: not found

Please help!!

Comment: Use `c=$(( val1 + val2))` instead of `c=$(expr $val1 + $val2`; the `expr` command is (mostly) obsolete in modern shells.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you put whitespace between the variable 'c' and the '='. Hence, the shell assumes `c` is a command and `=`, and `expr $val1 + $val2` are parameters given:

So instead of

```
c = `expr $val1 + $val2`
 ^ ^
```

write

```
c=$(expr $val1 + $val2)
```

All together:

```
echo Enter 2 values: 
read val1 val2
c=$(expr $val1 + $val2)
echo $c
```

Note that you can also get the result of the sum with:

```
echo $(( val1 + val2 ))
```

As a general rule, use `var=$(command)` to save a command output in a variable.